# Regarding bonjour domains

Tags: ios, bonjour

I'm trying to understand how the choice of the bonjour domain will influence device discovery on the network. I find the documentation somewhat unclear on some points, and would like to ask for clarification.

1. From [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNetServiceBrowser_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNetServiceBrowser/searchForRegistrationDomains):

   > Most network service browser clients do not have to use this method—it is sufficient to publish a service with the empty string, which registers it in any available registration domains automatically."

This seems like a recommendation. Lets put a pin on that.

2. From [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Articles/PublishingServices.html):

   > @""—Registers the service in the default set of domains. Pass this value unless you have a specific reason not to."

Reforces the recommendation, but what does this mean? What's the ***default*** set of domains? And what does that imply?

3. From the same link:

   > @"local"—Registers the service only on the local network. Pass this value if you need to prevent publishing your service over Back to My Mac or wide-area Bonjour.

What does publishing "over Back to My Mac or wide-area Bonjour" mean? Should I use this if I'm using bonjour for proximity only? Doesn't this contradict the recommendation?

4. Also from the same link:

> A user-specified domain—Registers the service in only the specified domain.

I actually tried this and the service doesn't even get advertised on the network. I get a call to the delegate method [netServiceWillPublish:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSNetServiceDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSNetServiceDelegate/netServiceWillPublish:) and that's it, nor [didPublish](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSNetServiceDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSNetServiceDelegate/netServiceDidPublish:) nor [didNotPublish](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSNetServiceDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSNetServiceDelegate/netService:didNotPublish:) are called afterwards. Is there a strict set of domains that can be used? I'm using simple names, like `test`.

Basically, it's still very unclear to me what the domain name accomplishes on the network. How does it influence the discovery process? Ou does it influence service matching? Does it have consequences on network performance? I know these seem like a lot of questions, but mostly, I think that if I understand what domains are for most of them will go away. Hopefully :)

Best.